# Python read from csv with condition for TimeSeriesGenerator

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, filter

I have a .csv file with many entries that looks like this:

```
observation1, observation2, tag
observation1, observation2, tag
...
b r e a k
observation1, observation2, tag
...
b r e a k
```

whereas the observations are some numbers and the tag the ground truth true/false.

the `break` part comes with the data and symbolizes the end of a file and the end of an observation chain. Datapoints within two `break` entries belong together. (All those datapoints are merged from multiple files into one huge csv).

With this data I am supposed to do some machine learning using the tensorflow TimeSeriesGenerator.

I found out however, that TSG uses a fixed time series chain length, which means I have to do some cutting/filtering of my data given.

Condition one, is that if a `true` appears in the chain, it has to be the last value. Condition two, that all chains consist of the same amount of entries.

This means, if say my chain length would be 3, then the following chains are allowed:

```
b r e a k
observation1, observation2, false
observation1, observation2, false
observation1, observation2, true
b r e a k
```

```
b r e a k
observation1, observation2, false
observation1, observation2, false
observation1, observation2, false
b r e a k
```

but not

```
b r e a k
observation1, observation2, false
observation1, observation2, true
observation1, observation2, false
b r e a k
```

A chain like this would also be allowed

```
observation1, observation2, false
observation1, observation2, false
observation1, observation2, false
observation1, observation2, true
```

as I could simply throw the first line away to get a length of 3.

But not a chain like this:

```
observation1, observation2, false
b r e a k
observation1, observation2, false
observation1, observation2, true
b r e a k
```

This means I need some way (my guess would be pandas) to filter the .csv file and find all occurences, where between to `b r e a k` lines there are at least x amount of `false` datapoints followed by a `true` or another `false`.

What would be a good way of achieving this filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution for this, I think, and this [Reverse part of a .csv file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006138), but it turned into a mini-project.

Here's what my main looks like:

```py
import csv

from series import series_iter, fix


BREAK_ROW = ["b r e a k", "", ""]
MIN_SERIES_LEN = 3
FIXED_SIZE = MIN_SERIES_LEN  # add a leading minus sign to trim the bottom rows of each series
PAD_ROW = ["0", "0", "0"]
TRUE_TAG = "true"

DEBUG_SEP_ROW = ["--"] * 3
wrote_first_series = False

with (
    open("input.csv", newline="") as f_in,  # the csv module docs recommends newline="" for all CSV reads & writes
    open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out,  # I changed "a" to "w" for my dev/testing
):
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    writer.writerow(next(reader))  # header

    for series in series_iter(reader, BREAK_ROW):
        # Condition 2: chain length
        if len(series) < MIN_SERIES_LEN:
            continue

        fixed_len_series = fix(series, PAD_ROW, FIXED_SIZE)

        # Condition 1: last true
        tags = [row[-1] for row in fixed_len_series]
        if TRUE_TAG in tags and tags[-1] != TRUE_TAG:
            continue

        if wrote_first_series:
            writer.writerow(DEBUG_SEP_ROW)  # for debuggin/visualizing

        writer.writerows(fixed_len_series)

        wrote_first_series = True  # for debuggin/visualizing
```

When I run that on this input.csv:

```
| Observation1   | Observation2   | Tag   |
|----------------|----------------|-------|
| b r e a k      |                |       |
| 1_observation1 | 1_observation2 | false |
| 1_observation1 | 1_observation2 | false |
| 1_observation1 | 1_observation2 | true  |
| b r e a k      |                |       |
| b r e a k      |                |       |
| 2_observation1 | 2_observation2 | false |
| 2_observation1 | 2_observation2 | false |
| 2_observation1 | 2_observation2 | false |
| b r e a k      |                |       |
| b r e a k      |                |       |
| 3_observation1 | 3_observation2 | false |
| 3_observation1 | 3_observation2 | true  |
| 3_observation1 | 3_observation2 | false |
| b r e a k      |                |       |
| 4_observation1 | 4_observation2 | false |
| 4_observation1 | 4_observation2 | false |
| 4_observation1 | 4_observation2 | false |
| 4_observation1 | 4_observation2 | true  |
| b r e a k      |                |       |
| 5_observation1 | 5_observation2 | false |
| b r e a k      |                |       |
| 6_observation1 | 6_observation2 | false |
| 6_observation1 | 6_observation2 | true  |
| b r e a k      |                |       |
```

I get this output.csv (the debug/visualization separator is enabled)

```
| Observation1   | Observation2   | Tag   |
|----------------|----------------|-------|
| 1_observation1 | 1_observation2 | false |
| 1_observation1 | 1_observation2 | false |
| 1_observation1 | 1_observation2 | true  |
| --             | --             | --    |
| 2_observation1 | 2_observation2 | false |
| 2_observation1 | 2_observation2 | false |
| 2_observation1 | 2_observation2 | false |
| --             | --             | --    |
| 4_observation1 | 4_observation2 | false |
| 4_observation1 | 4_observation2 | false |
| 4_observation1 | 4_observation2 | true  |
```

If I just comment out the two lines under `# Condition 2: chain length`, like the other question hints at, then fix() will pad smaller series:

```
| Observation1   | Observation2   | Tag   |
|----------------|----------------|-------|
| 1_observation1 | 1_observation2 | false |
| 1_observation1 | 1_observation2 | false |
| 1_observation1 | 1_observation2 | true  |
| --             | --             | --    |
| 2_observation1 | 2_observation2 | false |
| 2_observation1 | 2_observation2 | false |
| 2_observation1 | 2_observation2 | false |
| --             | --             | --    |
| 4_observation1 | 4_observation2 | false |
| 4_observation1 | 4_observation2 | false |
| 4_observation1 | 4_observation2 | true  |
| --             | --             | --    |
| 0              | 0              | 0     |
| 0              | 0              | 0     |
| 5_observation1 | 5_observation2 | false |
| --             | --             | --    |
| 0              | 0              | 0     |
| 6_observation1 | 6_observation2 | false |
| 6_observation1 | 6_observation2 | true  |
```

Series 3 is still dropped because of the true-must-be-last rule.

Here's the GitHub for all of this: https://github.com/zacharysyoung/StackOverflow/tree/SO-73006138

Comment: Wow, very interesting how in depth you went with this! I will definitely check this out in detail when I find some time this week.

For now, it does seem like what you wrote would fix both problems I have asked questions about in a very elegant way. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @studenprogrammer, you're welcome! The other answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73007189, was the genesis. As I was writing that I had this question also floating around in my brain. I just kept asking, "how much better or more clear can I make these ideas". I hope it's at least illuminating. :) Oh, and I've updated the code more than a bit since posting this, so just start with main.py to see something work right away, and then check out the README to see how you can control it all.

Comment: Hey, your github link somehow throws a 404. Could you per chance look into it, as I'd really like to dive into what you did

Comment: @studenprogrammer, I just checked and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself after tinkering around some more. I will post in case anyone else ever stumbles upon this:

What I did, was leave the chain length of x out for now and simply filtered for full `false` chains or chains of `falses` until first `true`. I also did not change the base file as initially intended, but wrote to a new file.

For my case, I then padded all chains but the longest with `0` observations to ensure unified chain length across all input chains. (Not included in this code example, there are many tutorials found online).

One could also cut all chains but the longest I guess, but I did not really try that.

Anyway, this code filters chains to the above described standard:

```
import csv

input_file = 'pathtofile'
output_file = 'outfile'

with open(input_file, 'r') as inp, open(output_file, 'a') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    helper_value = 0
    
    for row in reader:
        if(row[0]=='b r e a k'):
            helper_value = 0
            writer.writerow('s')
        else:
            if(helper_value==0):
                gt = row[3]
                if(gt=='false'):
                    writer.writerow(row)
                else:
                    writer.writerow(row)
                    helper_value=1
```

The `writer.writerow('s')` is to ensure seperate cases are kept seperate.